# Using MariaDB and mysql 5.7 at same time

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I was using MySQL server 5.7 and for another project, I needed to install MariaDB.
I have followed official instructions [Mariadb official download page](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=ossplanet&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=bionic--ubuntu_bionic&version=10.4)

after the install MySQL login in showing me following output

> Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>   Your MariaDB connection id is 46
>   Server version: 10.4.6-MariaDB-1:10.4.6+maria~bionic mariadb.org binary distribution
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
>
> MariaDB [(none)]> exit

how do I make both servers running up? maybe by different ports/ any identifier.

Comment: Have you seen https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/ ? If you're on windows can you adapt the advice there?

Comment: I am on Linux Ubuntu machine

Comment: just use Docker containers to deploy both services.ie : https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb, https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql . Use internal IP or exposed different ports

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

- Be sure they are in separate directories.
- Be sure to have separate my.cnf config files.
- Use different port numbers.  (Perhaps leave the existing one as 3306, then pick a bigger number for the second install.)

Plan B:

Put the second install in a VM.  There are still details to iron out of "hostname" and port.  Possibly the hostname of the VM cannot be "localhost", thereby forcing use of TCP/IP.